# Why map,filter,reduce takes the function parameter as first argument meanwhile function like sorted expects it as second parameter

Tags: python

How map  defined in python is

> map(function, iterable, ...)

as can be seen function is the first parameter the same goes for filter,reduce

but when I am checking functions like sorted they are defined

> sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False)

key being the function that can be used while sorting. I don't know Python well to say if there are other examples like sorted. But for starters, this seems a little a bit unorganized. Since I am coming from C++/D background in which I can almost all the time tell where the function parameter will go in the standard library it is a bit unorthodox for me.

Is there any historical or hierarchical reason why the function parameter is expected in different orders?

Comment: In this case, because it is most often used as `sorted(iterable)` without the other arguments. These functions are different to begin with, and the role of the function passed s an argument is different, I don't know why you think they would follow the same order.

Answer (score 2):

The actual signature of `map` is:

```
map(function, iterable, ...)
```

It can take more than one iterable, so making the function the first argument is the most sensible design.

You can argue about `filter`, there's no one "correct" way to design it, but making it the same order as `map` rather makes sense.

`sorted` doesn't require a `key` function, so it makes no sense to put it first.

Comment: I will edit my question now with actual signature. I hope it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can contribute a module into the python ecosystem. The lineage of any particular module is fairly unique (though I'm sure there are general families that share common lineages). While there will be attempts to standardise and agree on common conventions, there is a limit to what is possible.

As a result, some modules will have a set of paradigms that will differ vastly from other modules - they will have different focuses, and you just can't standardise down to the level you're looking for.

That being said, if you wanted to make that a priority, there's nothing stopping you from recasting all the non-standard things you find into a new suite of open source libraries and encouraging people to adopt them as the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The map() function design is different, the purpose of the design will surely determine the parameters that you pass into the function. The map() function executes a specified function for each item in an iterable, which is very different for the purpose of the sorted() function.